# How to validate form based on values and submit call out to another page accordingly?

Tags: javascript

How can I pause submission so that I can validate, check values, and possibly submit an xhtml callout based on the choices all before allowing the form to finally submit?

Have tried using various jquery methods found on here, using callbacks, setting timeouts, and holding in a while loop until everything's done. A lot of the alerts found in the code are only for troubleshooting/tracing purposes.

```
function completeTicket() {
    alert("fnOpenDiag Called");
    $("#dialog-confirm").html("Auto create return eTicket?");

    // Define the Dialog and its properties.
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Auto create return eTicket?",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                var quickissue = "Return <?php echo ($ticketRow['items_count'] >= 1 ? $ticketRow['items'] : 'Computer'); ?>";
                var selectedLocation2 = <?php echo ($ticketRow['Location_ID'] == '' ? 0 : $ticketRow['Location_ID']); ?>;
                xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
                if (xmlhttp==null) {
                  alert ("This browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
                }

                var url="xhtmlCallOut_QuickEticket.php?callerID=pc_ticket_detail&selectedLocation_ID=" + selectedLocation2 + "&tboxIssue=" + quickissue;

                xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
                    if (xmlhttp.responseText != 0){
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                }
                alert("ticket success");
                return true;
                $(this).dialog('close');
                //callback(true);
                //callback();
            },
                "No": function () {
                return true;
                $(this).dialog('close');
                //callback(false);
                //callback();
            }
        }
    }); 
}

function checkForm() {
      alert("checkform called");
      if(document.getElementById('assocCompany').selectedIndex == 0) {
          alert('Please associte this company with a known company name\nfrom the drop list.');
          document.getElementById('assocCompany').focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
      else if(document.getElementById('assignTech').selectedIndex == 0 && document.getElementById('status').selectedIndex >= 2){
          alert('You must define a technician first!');
          document.getElementById('assignTech').focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
      else if(RegisterForm.elements['status'].value == 3 && RegisterForm.elements['tboxreaspend'].value.length < 3){
          alert('You must give a reason for this ticket being changed to pending');
          document.getElementById('tboxreaspend').focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
      else if(RegisterForm.elements['tboxissue'].value.length < 3){
          alert('You must give a description of the issue');
          document.getElementById('tboxissue').focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
      else {
          pc_ticketdetail.actionbutton.disabled=true;
          return false;
      }
}

function showPendingReason() {
    var y = document.getElementById("status");
    var val = y.options[y.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val == 3) {
        $('#trReasPend').show();
    } else {
        $('#trReasPend').hide();
    }
}

function submitForm() {
    alert("submitform called");
    var x = document.getElementById("status");
    var valx = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    alert("statval is " + valx);
    if (valx == 4) {
        if (completeTicket()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
            alert("complete ticket done");
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (checkForm()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
            alert("checkform done");
        } else {
            alert("checkform FALSE return");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="pc_ticketdetail" id="pc_ticketdetail" method="post" onSubmit="return submitForm();">

<select name="status" id="status" onChange="javascript:showPendingReason();">
          <option<?php if($ticketRow['status'] == 1){ echo ' selected'; } ?> value="1">New</option>
          <option<?php if($ticketRow['status'] == 2){ echo ' selected'; } ?> value="2">Bench</option>
          <option<?php if($ticketRow['status'] == 3){ echo ' selected'; } ?> value="3">Pending</option>
          <option<?php if($ticketRow['status'] == 4){ echo ' selected'; } ?> value="4">Finished</option>      
          <?php if($ticketRow['status'] == 5){ 
              echo '<option selected value="5">Closed/Deleted</option>';
           } ?> 
        </select>
```

It currently seems to step through as expected except the "completeTicket" and "checkForm" functions are either not being called or not returning correctly. The form simply submits and closes when they should fail validation or open the modal dialogue and ask to create return ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on the (async - await) function in javaScript.
[async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: That could be a solution that will work, I'll look at implementing it on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: I'll help you with it if you need so don't hesitate to contact me.

Comment: I created an async function to call my completeTicket function, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The async function gets called and completes without actually waiting for the result.

Comment: Here's the function `code` async function asyncCallCompleteTicket() {
 alert("async Calling");
 var result = await completeTicket();
 alert("async Complete");
 if (result != NULL) {
  alert("async result not NULL");
  return true;
 } else {
  alert("async result IS NULL");
  return false;
 }
} `code` And I'm calling it like `code` if (asyncCallCompleteTicket()) `code` within the submitForm() function

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to properly format the code in a comment. The problem seems to be with my modal dialog box staying open to keep the function open. This works fine with a standard "confirm" box.

Answer (score 0):

your checkForm() never return false so is your completeTicket() never return true. you can initially define a variable as false and make it true if it meets a specific condition then return the variable to the main function.

```
  <script>
    function c(){   
    let isTrue = false;
    if(condition){
        isTrue = true;
    }
    return isTrue;
    }
    function d(){
     if(c()){
     alert("c returned true");
     } else{
         alert("c returned false");
       }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that all of the true or false returns were part of my troubleshooting efforts. Even with everything returning false, it still submitted the form and closed the page. I have not tried using a separate variable to return out of the function, I'll give it a try on Monday. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the alerts from under the `return` statements, that would help you in tracing the problem, because no code will run after you return from a function. Same thing for `$(this).dialog('close')`.

And I think that you should capture the event object before using it in `e.preventDefault()` so try to remove the `onSubmit` attribute from the form and adding the listener through jQuery like so :

```
$(YOUR_FORM_SELECTOR).submit(function(e) {
  // here you access to the e Object
})
```

I don't know if that related to the problem you have, Try describing what's happening exactly when you run the code.